# Is there a way to combine a folder listing and count of items?

Tags: directory

Is there a way to combine a folder listing and the count of items (like Windows does)?

This gives a detailed folder listing:

```
$ ls -l
```

This gives a count of displayed lines:

```
$ ls -l | wc -l
```

I don't know how to make both show up together. Thank you!

Comment: How about `ls -l && ls -l |wc -l`? You could make an alias out of it.

Comment: `ls -l` should give a file count (`total`) as the first line of output, no?

Comment: @steeldriver: No, it shows the total kilobytes on that directory level (excluding files in subdirectories); a number that is truly pointless.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help here. Jos, your suggestion does work, but I gave xhienne the answer because the ls command only executes once, and I can customize the output. Thank you for a working solution. It is better than what I was doing, and I would have used it if there had not been something more efficient. Tree suggested by Raffa is pretty cool too (and powerful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should more or less mimic what you have on Windows:

```
ls -l | awk '1; END { print NR - 1, "entries" }'

total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr  2 19:38 bar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr  2 19:38 foo
2 entries
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! I can alias this too and use it a lot.

Comment: Here's how I got the nested quotes to work as an alias, and I added color: alias ls="ls -l --color | awk '1; END { print NR - 1, \"entries\" }'"

Answer (score 1):

`tree` returns the total number of files and/or directories listed.

See [man tree](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/tree.1.html) for information and usage.

Comment: Raffa, thank you for the suggestion. Tree is pretty neat. It's got lots of options and is very powerful. I will definitely keep this on my system. It's things like this that make me wish I had switched from Windows to Linux many years ago.

Comment: Here is how i aliased tree: alias tree='tree -psL 1'

Comment: @KevinBerry Well done. You probably want to use a different alias name other than `tree` to be able to use the original `tree` command with different options later.

Comment: I had planned to use \tree when I wanted to use it without the alias, but I think your suggestion is better so I can avoid associating alias behavior with original command names. I'm just getting started with Linux so this is a great time for me to start good practices. Thank you!